# Python: check array dictionaries dependencies and check if it is circular

Tags: python, recursion

I have tricky task.
I have an array of dictionaries, structure is like this:

```
update_logics = [
    {
        "dependency_fields": [
            "population",
            "field_1",
        ],
        "update_logic": "{return CurrentState['population'] / CurrentState['area_km2'];}",
        "updated_field": "field_2",
    },
    {
        "dependency_fields": [
            "leader",
            "fields_2",
        ],
        "update_logic": "{return 'capital is: '+ CurrentState['capital'];}",
        "updated_field": "field_3",
    },
    {
        "dependency_fields": [
            "leader",
            "fields_3",
        ],
        "update_logic": "{return 'capital is: '+ CurrentState['capital'];}",
        "updated_field": "field_1",
    },
]
```

I would like to check each **updated_field** in the array. updated_field is dependent on dependency_fields

If I have circular dependency, I would like to return False or any mark. If it's not circular I would like to get the depth of dependencies.

I guess recursion is useful here, but do not understand how to work with arrays:

```
def check(arr, parent, el):
    for item in arr:
        item["updated_field"] ==el
        for child in item["dependency_fields"]:
            if child == el or child == parent:
                # circular
                return False
            else:
                # arr_for_check.append(child)
                check(arr, child, el)
```

So here recursion will work for first element in the list always.

Comment: what do you mean by `depth of dependencies` ? can you show in your case?

Comment: The easiest way would probably be to just install the `networkx` module and compose a directed graph of dependencies there, then use its loop-finding/depth functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expand on my comment – [just use `networkx` instead of reinventing the wheel](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/index.html)?

```
import networkx as nx

update_logics = [
    {"dependency_fields": ["population", "field_1"], "updated_field": "field_2"},
    {"dependency_fields": ["leader", "field_2"], "updated_field": "field_3"},
    {"dependency_fields": ["leader", "field_3"], "updated_field": "field_1"},
]

g = nx.DiGraph()
for l in update_logics:
    g.add_node(l["updated_field"])
    for dep in l["dependency_fields"]:
        g.add_edge(l["updated_field"], dep)

for f in g:
    all_deps = set()
    for depth, (node, edges) in enumerate(nx.bfs_successors(g, f)):
        all_deps.update(set(edges))
    print(f, "->", depth, all_deps)

print("===")
for cycle in nx.simple_cycles(g):
    print("CYCLE:", cycle)
```

outputs e.g.

```
field_2 -> 1 {'population', 'leader', 'field_3', 'field_1'}
population -> 0 set()
field_1 -> 2 {'field_3', 'field_2', 'population', 'leader'}
field_3 -> 1 {'population', 'field_2', 'field_1', 'leader'}
leader -> 0 set()
===
CYCLE: ['field_3', 'field_2', 'field_1']
```

Comment: Thanks so much, it works great. But also would like to have the list of fields that should be updated. Logic is the next, if user updated any field from dependency_fields array then should be triggered updated_field. I can check that updated field not in cycle, if it is I will raise an Exception, but can I use graph to know what fields should be updated based on dependency_fields.

Comment: Well, there's `bfs_predecessors`, which traces the graph of dependencies backwards...